# Plotly Dash - How to deal with huge states?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

Here is how my code works:

- the user enters some parameters and starts a very expensive calculation
- the result of this calculation is a very large array looking like: `[{"step":1, ...}, ... {"step":50000, ...}]`
- one step can be displayed on screen at a time (there is a button to jump to step x)

Here is approximately how I do:

- I put the result of the calculation inside Store(id=“result”).
- I create a callback that works approximately like that:

```py
@app.callback(Output("display", "children"), Output("result", "data"), [Input("jump-to-step-x-btn", "value")], [State("result", "data")])
    def foo(step, result):
        if ...:
            result = ... # possibly update the array
        return result[step], result
```

My problem is that, since the array is very big (nearly 500000 characters), it lags a little bit (approx. 0.5 sec) when the user tries to jump to a different step.

My guess is that it is because the array has to be sent and then retrieved from the server.

Any advice on what would be a good way to fix this issue?

Thank you very much and have a nice week.

Comment: If you suspect the data transfer is your bottleneck, then you could try make use of Dash's `ClientsideFunction` to do the processing in the browser. https://dash.plot.ly/performance has a section related to this with an example.

Comment: Ok. I think I'll go with that.
I was wondering if there was an option that would not require using JavaScript. I thought of solutions like keeping the states on the server in a dict that could be accessed using a user-unique id. But obviously that was not a good solution.
Anyway, thank you!

Comment: On that same link, there's some commentary about memoising function calls (i.e. your suggestion of caching states on the server). I'm not entirely sure with your application layout, but that's also an avenue you could explore.